# Webview not loading page in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm relatively new to programming in general, but I've attempted to find the answer to this and have failed to no end.

So basically I am attempting to create an application that has a map view scene, and that works fine. I then have another scene that is for web view. So when you go to the mapview scene there is a button that takes you to the webview scene.

The webview scene, however is not loading the web page at all, although when I create the webview part of the application in a different project with no other coding involved, it works just fine.

Here is the coding I have so far:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    MKMapView * mapview; IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView*webview;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;
-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)getlocation;



@end

--------


@implementation ViewController

@synthesize webview;
@synthesize mapview;


-(IBAction) getlocation {
    mapview.showsUserLocation= YES;
}

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {
    switch(((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            mapview.mapType= MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            mapview.mapType= MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        case 2:
            mapview.mapType= MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;

        default:
            break;



    }




}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]]];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

If you could help, would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if elaboration is required.

Comment: Of course web views don't load in Xcode. There's an overly simplistic reason for that: there are no web views in Xcode. What you *actually* meant is "in my [your] iOS application" - and that's completely different, and has nothing to do with Xcode whatsoever.

Comment: Can you provide code on how your passing a URL request to webView

Answer (score 0):

First make sure `viewDidLoad` is executing. There are some situations where it will not be executed.

Then check if `webview` is `nil` inside `viewDidLoad`. Most likely this is your problem. You probably aren't setting it properly, or you're setting it after `viewDidLoad` executes.

Best way to debug this is just to stick a breakpoint on the loadRequest line in your code, and have a look to see if:

1. it gets to your breakpoint at all
2. that the webview variable is not 0x00000000000

PS: you should delete these lines of code:

```
MKMapView * mapview; IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender;
@synthesize webview;
@synthesize mapview;
```

They are not needed anymore in the latest version of Xcode and wherever you learned it from is outdated.

Also, use `self.webview` instead of just `webview`. Accessing it directly is dangerous and can cause bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Create webView programmatically:

add in viewDidLoad:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.co.uk"]]];
                 [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: Can u plz explain the problem in creating webview programatically & in design time.

Comment: IB helps you be productive when your interfaces uses standard interfaces in a standard apple way using targets/actions.

That's a lot of trouble when you want the behaviour of the UI to be more organic, intuitive rather than just connected. You'll have to add other controllers to synthesize one semantic UX model out of several objects, and custom classes just don't play well within IB.

Comment: But there is no need of allocating the webview at runtime, because he already added it at design time.

Comment: True this is a alternative approach that doesn't require you to create object in IB

Answer (score 0):

please check web view delegate method

```
[webview setDelegate:self];
```